# run max3421 on device with 3.18 Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, embedded, device-tree

I need to run USB over SPI on the board which supports only 3.18 kernel. We use MAX3421 because driver for it is in kernel source.

I add to device-tree :

```
&spi_1 {
    status = "ok";
    usb@0 {
        compatible = "maxim,max3421";
        linux,modalias = "max3421-hcd";
        reg = <0>;
        spi-max-frequency = <26000000>;
        interrupt-parent = <&tlmm_pinmux>;
        interrupts = <42>;
    };
};
```

It appears in `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/soc/spi@78b6000/usb@0/`, but `/sys/bus/spi/devices/` is empty.

If I try to load kernel module it does not find the device on the bus and stay inactive.